# Configured Resources Per Flavor and BuildType Overwrites Each Other

Tags: android, gradle, resources, android-productflavors, android-build-type

I have several flavors for which I'd like to configure specific resources for on a per buildType basis.

The following configuration works perfectly if there's only one flavor, android recognizes the resource directories src/flavor1/res and src/flavor1/::buildType::/res as expected:

```
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        applicationId "com.flavor1"
        sourceSets {
            debug {
                res.srcDirs = [ 'src/flavor1/debug/res' ]
            }
            staging {
                res.srcDirs = [ 'src/flavor1/staging/res' ]
            }
            release {
                res.srcDirs = [ 'src/flavor1/release/res' ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I add more than one flavor, the resource directory for the last flavor defined is the only one recognized regardless of what variant is currently selected in Android Studio:

```
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        applicationId "com.flavor1"
        sourceSets {
            debug {
                res.srcDirs = [ 'src/flavor1/debug/res' ]
            }
            staging {
                res.srcDirs = [ 'src/flavor1/staging/res' ]
            }
            release {
                res.srcDirs = [ 'src/flavor1/release/res' ]
            }
        }
    }
    flavor2 {
        applicationId "com.flavor2"
        sourceSets {
            debug {
                res.srcDirs = [ 'src/flavor2/debug/res' ]
            }
            staging {
                res.srcDirs = [ 'src/flavor2/staging/res' ]
            }
            release {
                res.srcDirs = [ 'src/flavor2/release/res' ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above configuration, when I select flavor1Debug, for example, the following directories are recognized as the resource directories:

```
src/flavor1/res
src/flavor2/debug/res
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What's is the pkg name in manifest of build dir ?

Comment: What does the package name in the manifest have to do with this issue?

Comment: In case anyone is interested in this issue, I've opened a bug report with Google: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230068